# Websocket php и странности после 1дневного простоя

Tags: php, websocket

Используется ratchet. На сайте производится авторизация через openid. Сессии хранятся в базе. На событие onMessage происходит получение куки с id сессии у клиента и получение данных по id из базы.

Авторизация проверяется через существование определенного ключа в сессии.

При 1-2х дневной работе демона происходит следующее. Человек заходит на сайт, авторизуется, пробует к примеру отправить сообщение в чате, ему в ответ демон пишет что вы не авторизованы.Помогает перезапуск демона. В чем может быть собственно проблема? Вот сейчас демон простоял несколько часов, общая память увеличилась на 2 мб. Я думаю тут не утечка памяти, а что-то другое.

Если пишет что не авторизован, то следовательно не может найти ключ в сессии в бд, но id сессии он получает, т.к в консоли он выводится. Запись в бд тоже присутствует. Я предполагаю что тут проблема с базой(mysql), может что-то не то в кфг(стоят дефолтные на debianе). Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался. Жду каких либо предположений. Спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37099/discussion-on-question-by-azimut-websocket-php----1-).

Answer (score 2):

Была такая же фигня. Правда сервер на Си, но подключение к базе mysql. Через сутки связь с базой теряется. Как верно указывали предыдущие ораторы (вот только почему-то стесняются постить свои мысли в ответы)- соединение при простое рвёт сама база. Фиксится настройкой в конфиге (/etc/mysql/***my.cnf***) одного значения - ***wait_timeout*** = {количество секунд}. Не пробуйте уменьшать его до одной минуты и тестировать таким образом - это бЕстолку. Выставьте ***2000000*** (ребутните) и посмотрите как поведет себя соединение через сутки простоя (не подключайтесь к нему в течение суток).

И еще... Есть такая штука как ***http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.ping.php*** . Мне не помогала (ее аналог на Си), но может у Вас будет самое то.